# Tikz Nozzle Design

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

I'm new to Tikz and I would like some help with a nozzle I'm designing (a nozzle for [reaction control thrusters](http://www.space1.com/Artifacts/Apollo_Artifacts/SM_RCS_Thruster/RCS_R-4D_thruster_400.jpg)).

I want to place a couple of nozzles on the sides of a cube. My idea was to use a [simple cone](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/truncated-cone/) for the nozzle.

Copying the code for the cone:

```
    % Cone
    \draw[dashed,color=gray] (0,0) arc (-90:90:0.5 and 1.5);% right half of the left ellipse
    \draw[semithick] (0,0) -- (4,1);% bottom line
    \draw[semithick] (0,3) -- (4,2);% top line
    \draw[semithick] (0,0) arc (270:90:0.5 and 1.5);% left half of the left ellipse
    \draw[semithick] (4,1.5) ellipse (0.166 and 0.5);% right ellipse
```

I would like to know how I can turn this into a command so that I can call this code everytime I need to draw the cone? And how can I rotate/translate/scale it to stick it to the faces of my cube? Any other suggestions to solve this problem are very much welcome!

I would like to do this in 3D so that I can change the perspective as well.

--EDIT--

The cone code is in 2D so I'm working on a 3D equivalent now.

Comment: If you can use TikZ/PGF version 3 `pic`s are very close to what you are asking for (section 18 of manual)

Answer (score 2):

If you put your drawing code inside a `scope` environment, you can change the translation, rotation and scaling without changing the drawing code itself. You can then put all of this in a `\newcommand` to create one command that draws a translated, rotated, scaled nozzle:

```
\newcommand*{\nozzle}[3]{
\begin{scope}[shift = {#1}, rotate = #2, scale = #3]
    \draw[dashed,color=gray] (0,0) arc (-90:90:0.5 and 1.5);% right half of the left ellipse
    \draw[semithick] (0,0) -- (4,1);% bottom line
    \draw[semithick] (0,3) -- (4,2);% top line
    \draw[semithick] (0,0) arc (270:90:0.5 and 1.5);% left half of the left ellipse
    \draw[semithick] (4,1.5) ellipse (0.166 and 0.5);% right ellipse
\end{scope}}
\nozzle{(0,  0)}{ 0}{1.0}
\nozzle{(0,  4)}{45}{1.5}
\nozzle{(0, 10)}{90}{0.5}
```

I’m not sure what you mean by sticking this to the faces of your cube. You could tweak the transformation manually until you are satisfied, but if you want a true 3D perspective (or orthogonal) transformation, things will become more complicated.

Comment: I have the coordinates of my vertices and I just want to place the bottom of my cone on a vertex (pointing in a certain direction). What do you mean with that a true 3D perspective becomes more complicated? If i can rotate and translate the cone I have a 3D drawing, not?

Comment: If you want to accurately draw a 3D model, then you either have to compute the 3D → 2D projection yourself, or you have to use a package that does this for you. If you just want to create a “fake 3D” picture that looks nice, the above should be sufficient.

Comment: Yes I see the problem now :( I didn't look close enough at the cone code...it's 2D. I want a 3D picture. If I make a cone in 3D will the same code you used (with shiff/rotate/scale) work as well? I guess for 3D rotations I need 3 angles